# How to convert SSR to Sigma Sqared of the Error Term-Matrix OLS

Tags: variance, least-squares

I'm trying to determine the variance of the error term without the residuals or the original X or Y vectors. I do have SSR. Is sigma squared of the error term just SSR/n-1?

For some reason I can't find this among tutorials. Thanks

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "SSR."

Comment: Sum of squared residuals. Some books call it SSE for sum squared errors.

Comment: And other books use "SSR" for the sum of squares of the *regression* (which is related to $1-R^2$). That's why it's crucial to explain your abbreviations!  Regardless, the usual unbiased estimator is SSR/(n-1) only when -- *including any intercept* -- there is just one regressor.  The general answer is found in many threads here: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+error+variance+n-p .